# Compile a class dynamically and store in build folder

Tags: java, dynamic, compilation

I am currently using NetBeans to create a program which allows users to write and execute their own code. So far I have this method which i use to compile their code:

```
public boolean compileClass(String userClassName){

    int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, "src/uk/learningAid/UserInputs/"+userClassName+".java");

        if(compilationResult == 0){
            System.out.println("Compilation Successful");
            return true;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
            return false;
        }
}
```

However, this creates a `.class` file within the same package as the .java file in the `src` folder, and also a `.class` file in the `build` folder. What I want is to only have the `.class` in the `build` folder and not in the `src` folder.

Furthermore, if the user types in new code to be executed, the method above will create a new `.class` representation of the user's code within the `src` folder, but it wont update the `.class` in the `build` folder.

Comment: The [options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/Tool.html#run%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String...%29) are pretty limited. Maybe copy the src file to the build directory, and run the compile on the src there. Because I don't think you get more than one output per compile.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Since the method is creating and updating the .class in the src folder, could I not use Reflection to load the class every time the user updates their code? If so, would you be able to provide example of that?

Comment: That is not a small ask. Once a class is loaded by the class loader it is not reloaded (nor is the disk scanned for updates). Sounds like you want a fairly complex [custom class-loader](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/v1r4m2/topic/com.ibm.java.doc.diagnostics.142/html/id1100.html?path=0_2_2_4#id1100).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Maven embedder API and adopt the Maven project structure (or define your own structure through the pom.xml file).

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3-LATEST/maven-embedder/index.html